# SQL group by with Rollup misunderstanding?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rollup

Ive read [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/24/sql-server-introduction-to-rollup-clause/) about it ( use it rarely)

but I have a problem understanding something :

this is the datasource :

[image]

according to this query :

```
SELECT Country,[State],City,
SUM ([Population (in Millions)]) AS [Population (in Millions)]
FROM tblPopulation
GROUP BY Country,[State],City WITH ROLLUP
```

if im grouping by  : *Country*, *State*, **City**

so every row is distinct ! ( because of the city)

so after `every` row -  there should be a "*middle sum* "

but there isn't.

what am I missing ?

p.s. the result is  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last column never gets a "middle sum" even if it is not distinct. Lets say all your cities were either "A" or "B". You wouldn't want a "middle sum" per city because you already have it! You have the sums for "A" and "B" already. Also, you couldn't distinguish the "middle sums" for "A" and "B" because they were both set to null. The two rows would be identical (with different counts).

Comment: why do i get a sum line after chaning state and not after changing city ? they both appear at the group by ...?

Comment: Remove city from the query and you won't get a sum line after state either. The *last* column doesn't get one. City is the last one.

Comment: where does it says ( by definition) that the last column doesnt get one ...?

Comment: Just try it. Remove city from the list and you will see. Can you post the exact result you would like to see (in a small example)?